# assign length units after number defined

Tags: lengths, trignometry

I have a latex which which does some calculations, but the functions are not available for Lengths. I would like to be able to assign the unit to the output of the math. The following succeeds without assigning units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{xparse}

% #1 is unitless length
% #2 is angle in degrees
% #3 is for output selection
\NewDocumentCommand\DoMath{m m m}
{
\COPY{#1}{\a}
\COPY{#2}{\t}
\def\choice{#3}
\DEGREESSIN{\t}{\st}
\DEGREESCOS{\t}{\ct}
\DEGREESTAN{\t}{\tt}
\DIVIDE{\a}{\tt}{\b}
\DIVIDE{\a}{\st}{\c}


\ifnum #3=1
    \a
\else
    \ifnum #3=2
        \b
    \else
        \ifnum #3 =3
            \c
        \else
            \ifnum #3 =4
                \t
            \else
                \a
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
\fi
}


\NewDocumentCommand\DoMathTest{m m}
{
\DoMath{#1}{#2}{1} %return a (height)

\DoMath{#1}{#2}{2} % return b (width)

\DoMath{#1}{#2}{3} % return c (hypotenuse)

\DoMath{#1}{#2}{4} % return t (angle)

\DoMath{#1}{#2}{5} % test incorrect selection returns a (height)

}


\begin{document}
\DoMathTest{10}{30} % this function succeeds
\end{document}
```

and the outputs is

> 10
>
> 17.32106
>
> 20.00061
>
> 30
>
> 10

The following fails

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{xparse}

% #1 is unitless length
% #2 is angle in degrees
% #3 is for output selection
\NewDocumentCommand\DoMath{m m m}
{
\COPY{#1}{\a}
\COPY{#2}{\t}
\def\choice{#3}
\DEGREESSIN{\t}{\st}
\DEGREESCOS{\t}{\ct}
\DEGREESTAN{\t}{\tt}
\DIVIDE{\a}{\tt}{\b}
\DIVIDE{\a}{\st}{\c}


\ifnum #3=1
    \a
\else
    \ifnum #3=2
        \b
    \else
        \ifnum #3 =3
            \c
        \else
            \ifnum #3 =4
                \t
            \else
                \a
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
\fi
}



\NewDocumentCommand\DoMathTest{m m m}
{

\newlength{\ti}
%fails around here
\setlength{\ti}{{\DoMath{#1}{#2}{1}}#3} %return a
\ti

\DoMath{#1}{#2}{2} % return b

\DoMath{#1}{#2}{3} % return c

\DoMath{#1}{#2}{5} % test incorrect selection return's a

}

\begin{document}
\DoMathTest{10}{30}{in} % this function succeeds
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setlength{\ti}{anything}#3}`  would fail because of the `{}` you can not do `\setlength{\ti}{1}in}`   but even without `{}`  the argument needs to expand to a length but `\DoMath` is not expandable, it does `\def` and other assigments.

Comment: Note that TeX lengths are intended for typesetting and have a limited range of values allowed (fixed point, 1pt=65536sp). You probably should look at siunitx instead.

Comment: This is intended for a _TIKZ_ diagram, but i figured that was not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\DoMath` command is not fully expandable, so `\setlength` fails badly.

You can use instead the expandable floating point commands of `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

% #1 is unitless length
% #2 is angle in degrees
% #3 is for output selection

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\DoMath{m m m}
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #3 }
   {
    {1}{#1}
    {2}{\fp_eval:n { (#1)/tand(#2) }}
    {3}{\fp_eval:n { (#1)/sind(#2) }}
    {4}{#2}
   }
   {#1}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand\DoMathTest{m m}{%
  \DoMath{#1}{#2}{1}% return a (height)

  \DoMath{#1}{#2}{2}% return b (width)

  \DoMath{#1}{#2}{3}% return c (hypotenuse)

  \DoMath{#1}{#2}{4}% return t (angle)

  \DoMath{#1}{#2}{5}% test incorrect selection returns a (height)
}

\newlength{\ti}

\NewDocumentCommand\DoMathTestAgain{m m m}{%
  \setlength{\ti}{\DoMath{#1}{#2}{1}#3}% return a
  \the\ti
}

\begin{document}

\DoMathTest{10}{30}

\DoMathTestAgain{10}{30}{in}

\end{document}
```

[image]